# Some files in C:\ hidden even though hidden attribute is not set, how to identify them?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, file-attributes

I found this on a Windows XP machine and as well as a Windows 7 machine. That is certain files in C drive (not anywhere else yet), are hidden, though their hidden attribute is false (or unchecked). Those files look pale like other hidden files when made visible (from folder options) and they get hidden when we set "do not show hidden files" in folder options.

Those files in my machine as I see are `autoexec.bat` and `config.sys` in C:. Is there a way to identify such files, say from some script, registry or from programming environment? Basically I was trying to get the count of non-hidden files in a directory, and my application fails when it attempts to get count of files in C:. What happens is that the application counts those two files (since its attribute is not hidden), but from a visual standpoint, they are pale/hidden normally.

---

My point is not about `System Files` which requires a special setting in folder options to be shown. Such files and folders do have hidden attribute `checked` (though the checkbox in their case is readonly). They are in most ways similar to normal hidden files/folders. My question is about files that *appear hidden* but without hidden attribute. To see what is that, see your C drive for the files I mentioned if they happen to be there..

Comment: Are these perhaps system files? The attribute would be +S instead of +H. You can check from a command prompt window.

Comment: No they are not system files.. I will update my question

Comment: Interesting, havn't notice this phenomenon before. I tried several tests, and found (1) `AUTOEXEC.BAT` or `CONFIG.SYS` must be named in **UPPERcase**, or they will not looks like hidden file. (2) `AUTOEXEC.BAT` or `CONFIG.SYS` must be placed in **root directory of any drive**. If they're not in root directory, then they're not looks like hidden file.  I *guess* explorer.exe internally treat these special files as system files. [Explorer++](http://www.explorerplusplus.com/) does not treat these two file as hidden/system file because they do not have +H or +S attributes.

Comment: @LiuYan刘研 what is even more interesting is that when u select those two files, you see in the details panel that they do have hidden property. But if u see properties by pressing alt+enter, the hidden attribute is surprisingly not there!! And my code (C#.NET) detects them as not hidden in the end :X :)

Comment: @LiuYan刘研 That UPPERcase thing is interesting. DO you have any idea why it is so?

Comment: I have no idea, all I can *guess* is explorer.exe internally treat these special files as system files. and btw, your code behavior act as same as Explorer++ does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some research when I was writing my own [usb_vaccine](https://github.com/Explorer09/usb_vaccine) script. AFAIK, only **three** files will be displayed with **fake** *Hidden and System* attributes in Windows Explorer:

- COMMAND.COM
- autoexec.bat
- config.sys

The hiding begins with Windows XP version of Windows Explorer.

Some people say their casing matters on whether they will be hidden, but I have no time to verify that (since Windows file systems are case-insensitive anyway).

However, I should point out, that this hiding behavior happens on both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Windows Explorer. This means if you inserted an  hard disk with a 32-bit Windows on a 64-bit Windows machine, you *will* see these 3 files hidden (fake Hidden and System attributes) without Hidden attributes set officially in filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

They are hidden because they are operation system files although they are not hidden in the attribute. Just uncheck the line in the picture that i have highlighted. And you will be able to see the system files.

Comment: sorry for being rude, but this isn't what I am talking about. I updated my question

Comment: There is no way to hide any file without checking hidden in attribute. Unless it is a system file

Comment: Titan, you dont get it. I do agree there is no way for us, end users. But these are not files I or you created. These files come with operating system, or from some heavy weight third party application. Something programmatically must have created them. FYI, system files do have their hidden attribute checked, in a readonly manner. Please read my question..

Comment: @nawfal I think this command will do it. "dir /as" type this in cmd, this command will show system files. /a switch is used to show attrib files where "s" stand for system file. And i don't have those files you mentioned above.

Comment: Ok Titan, thanks for that much. Let me see and get back to you asap. Could you remove the pic, and texts that are not related to my problem. It makes no sense to be there..

Comment: Titan, I was asking you to edit the answer so that its related to my question. Please note from my question that my problem is not related to system files. System files do have hidden attribute. Please press Alt+Enter from any system file and see for yourself. If I had downvote privilege, I would have downvoted this!

Comment: And no, dir /as doesn't work. It lists just the system files. I have nothing to do with that!